# How to use a private gem server hosted gem when building another gem

Tags: rubygems, gemspecs

If I've built a private gem (hosted internally at my company, for instance), then I want to reuse that gem in another gem (not app!) that I'm building, how do I do that?

Where do I put my dependencies and tell my new gem how to find the old (already built) privately hosted gem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this took me awhile to figure out, because the answer is, it's in TWO places.  Do this:

- In your gem's Gemfile (yes, Gemfile, not .gemspec), add the source line for your private gem server.  If you're also pulling from RubyGems, then it'll look something like this:

> ```
> source 'http://rubygems.org'
> source 'http://myrubygems.mycompany.example.com:8808'  # Or wherever your gems are hosted internally (or externally)
> gemspec
> ```

- Then, in your mynewgem.gemspec put the following:

> ```
> Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
>   # [...]
>   gem.add_dependency 'myoldgem'  # the gem hosted at myrubygems.mycompany.example.com:8808
> end
> ```

The reason this works is probably obvious: Your Gemfile specifies the source for your gems and your .gemspec specifies the dependencies.

Hope this saves someone a few minutes.